# Get COM+ Applications List

Tags: powershell

I am building a report for COM+ Application Settings. 
My first step is to read all the Applications.

On my Local Computer thats not a problem, i do it like this:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")

$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications") 

$applications.Populate() 

foreach ($application in $applications)
{
        write-host $application.Name
}
```

This is working very well! But i need to get the Information from a remote server. I tried to do it like this:

```
$Server = "chvmes01;chvmes02"
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$ServerArr = $Server.Split(";",$option)

foreach($s in $ServerArr){
        $comAdmin = Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {New-Object -Com "ComAdmin.ComAdminCatalog"}

        $applications = Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {param($comAdmin) $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")} -ArgumentList $comAdmin

        Remove-PSSession $session
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [Deserialized.System.__ComObject#{790c6e0b-9194-4cc9-9426-a48a63185696}]
>   does not contain a method named 'GetCollection'.

I also tried to combine the commands like this:

```
 $command1 = {
   New-Object -Com "ComAdmin.ComAdminCatalog" |
   .GetCollection("Applications")
}


$applications = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $command1
```

Here i get the following error:

> The term '.GetCollection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

What am i missing??

Comment: Can you try this ? https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-Remote-Applications-4c2720d4

Comment: This is for installed programms, i tried it.. What i need is different... I need to get is the Com+ applications.. Not the Normal Applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe servers to a `Invoke-Command` run the full command in the `-scriptblock`

```
@("chvmes01","chvmes02") | Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
    $comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")
    $applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")    
    $applications.Populate()    
    $applications | %{
        write-host $_.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, working exactly like expected! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Comment only, just in case ueful to anyone: I needed two levels and went for this (single computer but could be scripted against others of course)

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")    
$applications.Populate()  

foreach ($AppObject in $applications) {
    "`nApplication  $($appObject.key)   $($appObject.Name)    ID: $($appObject.Value("Identity"))"
    $Components = $applications.GetCollection("Components", $AppObject.Key) 
    $Components.populate()
    $components | foreach-object {
        "Component    $($_.key)   $($_.Name)" }
    }
```